# Who broke or break?

Tags: past-tense

which one is right:

> 1. He was the first who break the silence
> 2. He was the first who broke the silence
> 3. He was the first to break the silence
> 4. He was the first to broke the silence

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

The correct sentence here is your third, ***He was the first to break the silence.***

General usage will also accept the second, ***He was the first who broke the silence.*** However, most teachers of English will point it out as incorrect, and give you the correct form as above.

The other two sentences use incorrect verb forms.

In the first sentence, you have mismatched tense for the verb in the phrase *...who **break** the silence*. **Break** is a present form, but by saying *He was...*, you have placed the sentence as a whole in the past. This error is corrected in your second sentence.

In the fourth sentence, "to {something}" is the infinitive form of a verb, but "broke" is the past tense of "to break". This is trying to use the past as the infinitive. The third sentence corrects this error.